# EPPlus портит даты

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

В общем, читаю Excel, где есть колонки с датой.

Когда я считываю Value в переменную, то дата превращается в такое число 38574.

Как можно это пофиксить?

В excel ячейка с датой выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда считываю ячейку

```
 var cellVal = ws.Cells[i, kvp.Item1].Value?.ToString().Trim()??"";
```

получаю вот такую цифру:

38574

Если вызвать DateTime.FromOADate, то дата преобразуется в нормальную.

1)Можно ли этого избежать и сразу получать нормальную дату?

2)Если нет, то как я могу понять, что число является датой, что бы вызвать преобразование?

Comment: Дополнил, немного.

Comment: Не портит. Дата в Excel - количество дней, начиная с 01.01.1900, а отображение в виде даты - это всего лишь формат ячейки, визуальное представление. Определить, чем является значение - датой или обычным десятичным числом - можно по формату ячейки.

Comment: @vikttur, как я могу через Epplus проверить формат ячейки?

Comment: Совершенно не знаю С#, показал информацию по *Excel* (вдруг поможет...)

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно попробовать `worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format == ''DD.MM.YY"` но это не точно, придется много таких проверок писать если у вас много форматов ячеек.

Comment: Нашел решение, если вызвать Text, а не Value, то дата приходит нормальной.

Comment: раз нашлось решение, может оформите ответом?

Answer (score 4):

Комментить пока не могу. Поэтому пользуюсь формой ответа.

Я, как и [@vikttur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7746/vikttur) Пастернака (си-диез) тоже не читал. Но по Екселю он правильно написал, только очень кратко. Я местами его повторю (не в упрек :))

Все твои телодвижения, упомянутые в вопросе и в комменте - от лукавого. Получилось, типо, и ладно...

То, что ты видишь на экране в ячейке Екселя - форматированное представление даты. А дата у него состоит из целой части - дни откуда-то там, и дробной части текущих суток. По сути - `Double`. Но есть нюансы (мы не про них), поэтому Ексель, а по сути - не Ексель, а VBA, для хранения даты использует свой, суррогатный тип данных `Date`.

Вот тут и возникает основной момент: начиная манипулировать с датой нужно явно привести ее в `Double` `dDate_As_Double = CDbl(dDate_As_Date)`. После этого можно совершать различные манипуляции. Ну, а когда надо будет ее вернуть VBA взад - так же, явно, конвертнуть обратно `dDate_As_Date = CDate(dDate_As_Double)`.

Т.е. на VBA это выглядело бы так:

```
'
dDate_As_Date_Src = ws.Cells[i, kvp.Item1].Value
dDate_As_Double_Src = CDbl(dDate_As_Date_Src)

' ... do any you want, For example:
dDate_As_Double_Tgt = dDate_As_Double_Src + 5             ' add 5 days
dDate_As_Double_Tgt = dDate_As_Double_Tgt - (5 / 24)      ' minus 5 hours
dDate_As_Double_Tgt = dDate_As_Double_Tgt + (31 / 1440)   ' plus 31 minutes
dDate_As_Double_Tgt = dDate_As_Double_Tgt + (17 / 86400)  ' plus 17 seconds
dDate_As_Double_Tgt = dDate_As_Double_Tgt - (0.003141592) ' minus Pi milliseconds 

dDate_As_Date_Tgt = CDate(dDate_As_Double)
ws.Cells[i, kvp.Item1].Value = dDate_As_Date_Tgt
'
```

Плюсов у такого подхода - мульон. Например:
- все эти ужимки и прыжки с первым днем недели, первой неделей года, началом недели каким днем - остаются за скобками простой арифметики;
- разница между датами считается влет;
- доступны манипуляции с отрицательными величинами;
- етсетера, етсетера, как писал великий летчик-артиллерист АС - Пушкин. 
.

---

**Add:**

> Однако, все равно хотелось бы знать способ определения формата ячеек.

Что значит "*определения*"?

Велика и могуча русская языка. Редкий птиц ... etc. :)

Если узнать формат: есть RW свойство у ячейки Cells(1,1).NumberFormat, емнип...
Если задать формат: опять через него же... :)

Запиши рекордером макрос - будет тебе рыба. По встроенным форматам - Ф1. По пользовательским помощь слабовата, но тоже сгодится для начала.

Только зачем, в контексте вышеизложенного? Ты же знаешь, к какой ячейке ты обращаешься и что в ней лежит. Хотя, если дата сильно гуляет по точности и величине в результате вычислений, то может и понадобится изменить ее формат (читай - экранное представление).
.

Comment: 2All - спасибо всем за оценку этого маленького эссе. Теперь я уже могу комментить и не быть столь многословным :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение в виде вызова Text вместо Value.

Однако, все равно хотелось бы знать способ определения формата ячеек.